# Customer e-mail is missing in order email Magento 2. How to add it?

Tags: magento2

Customer e-mail is missing in order email Magento 2. How to add it?
[image]

Comment: Please check var/log folder. Some exception happens at order email.Iguess that you might do some code  at order email item phtml file

Answer (score 0):

**Please check the eMail template is overridden in admin (transnational email section) from there we can debug or we can get the mailid.**